# lexicographic compare with unknown bytes size - in c

Tags: c

how to do a lexicographic compare between two pointers with unknown byte size,
assuming both array size is equal,
eg implementing the following function to return -1 or 0 or 1 based on the comparecement and converting each byte to ascii

```
compare(const void *p1, const void *p2, int size)
```

EDIT: i added another argument with the size of bytes to compare, how can i cast each byte to char and compare between them ?

Comment: the arrays have unknown size? how would that work?

Comment: its not possible without the array size ?

Comment: you need to know how many array elements to compare

Comment: if i will add count argument, how can i implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`strcmp(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html) function.

**Update**

If your arrays are not of ASCII strings and may contain the `0x00` byte at any position without actually meaning anything, then you'll need the length as Oli points out, so you can use the [`memcmp(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcmp.html) function:

```
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

**Update #2**

Okay, now that we've established you *also* want the byte that differs, you'll need your own function. Something like this (untested):

```
size_t cmp(const unsigned char *c1, const unsigned char *c2, ssize_t n) {
    ssize_t i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (c1[i] != c2[i])
            return i;
    }
    -1;
}
```

This will let you find the byte values for whichever bytes differ. Note the `-1` return in case of no difference. This limits you to comparing objects whose size fit entirely in a `ssize_t`, which is smaller than the `size_t` type -- but since you're comparing two of them, I figure each one gets half the process address space at most anyway.

Comment: True, but he did mention "ascii", which gave me the courage to post the answer. :)

Comment: Perhaps you should look into Oli's recommendation of iterating through the arrays yourself -- `s1[i]` only makes sense if you know the _type_ of your array, and `const void *` doesn't tell the compiler what the size of each element is. (The internals will treat each array as `n` bytes long, but you can't just dereference an untyped array without performing casting...) Maybe re-edit your question with the task you're trying to solve?

Comment: @sarnold ok, now it makes sense ?

Comment: Sorry, not really -- `memcmp(a,b,n)` will return negative or positive based on the lexicographic sort depending upon which one is "greater than" or "less than" -- or if the two are equal, it'll return `0`. If you want to know which specific byte is different, then you'll have to write a loop to do the work for you. It might not be as fast as `memcmp(3)`, but it _will_ let you find out which bytes differ, if any.

Comment: @sarnold it needs to be in a loop, but how can i compare between the two values  inside the loop?

Comment: @Shlomi Komemi a void pointer can be converted to any other pointer. Just do `char *c1 = p1, *c2 = p2;` and compare their values e.g. `if(*c1 < *c2 )`

Answer (score 0):

You need some way of knowing the size.  Either explicitly (e.g. with a `size` argument or field in your data), or implicitly (e.g. with a null terminator).

Comment: @ShlomiKomemi: By iterating through the arrays until one differs from the other, or until you reach the end.